# $C^{\infty}$ functions and isolated zeroes

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, roots

I am trying to solve the following problem from the [SISSA 2010 Test](http://www.math.sissa.it/sites/default/files/Entrance_Examinations_pdf/LM-10.pdf):

> $\textbf{2.}~$  Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ be a $C^{\infty}$ function with the following property: if $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$ is such that $f(x,y)=0$ then
>
> 1. The gradient vector $\nabla f(x,y)$ is singular.
> 2. The Hessian matrix $Hf(x,y)$ is nonsingular.
>
> Show that $f$ admits only isolated zeroes.

Let $Z=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:f(x,y)=0\}$ be the set of zeroes of $f$. We want to show that $Z$ is totally disconnected or that, equivalently, given a point $(x_0,y_0)\in Z(f)$ there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $U \cap Z(f)=\{(x_0,y_0)\}$.

Let $(x_0,y_0)$ be such that $f(x_0,y_0)=0$. I understand that under these hypotheses, we can write the second order Taylor expansion for $f$,
$$f(x,y)=f(x_0,y_0)+\nabla f(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0,y-y_0)+(x-x_0,y-y_0)\cdot Hf(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0,y-y_0)+o(||(x-x_0,y-y_0)||^2)$$
If $\nabla f(x_0,y_0)$ is singular, then it has rank zero, so 
$$f(x,y)=(x-x_0,y-y_0)\cdot Hf(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0,y-y_0)+o(||(x-x_0,y-y_0)||^2)$$
Basically, $f$ "looks" like a nondegenerate quadratic polinomial in a neighbourhood of $(x_0,y_0)$. I tried thinking about what happens around zeroes of two-variable quadratic polynomials, but I could not proceed any further.

How can I go on constructing the neighbourhood $U$ in which $f$ is non-zero except at $(x_0,y_0)$?

Comment: Are you sure about $O(|...|^2)$ in your Taylor series? Shouldn't it be $3$?

Comment: @Behnam Talking about the $O$ you are correct indeed, I meant to write $o$. Sure, if the Hessian is positive/negative definite everything works out quite smoothly. Why should the Hessian have only positive or negative eigenvalues? Could it not be e.g. $\begin{pmatrix}1 &0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$? It seems like it somehow contradicts property (1.), but I'm not able to show it clearly.

Comment: Yeah, I confused the problem with another one. But, wait a minute! This question became interesting: Take $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ at point $(0,0).$ It's gradient is zero, while its Hessian is twice that matrix you said. But zeros are along lines $|y|=|x|.$ This is not a contradiction since $f$ does not satisfy 1) whenever $f=0$.

Comment: Oh! Then this solves the problem as below: If there is an accumulation point for zeros of $f$, then the same points are zeros of $Df$, thus $Df$ has an accumulating sequence of zeros. But $D^2f$ is not zero when $f=Df=0.$ (In other words, we are working with function $f_x$ and $f_y$. Their derivative is not zero when $f_x=f_y=0$, so the zeros cannot accumulate.)